# How do I stop the RabbitMQ server on localhost

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I installed RabbitMQ server on OS X, and started it on command line. Now, it is not obvious that how I should stop it from running? After I did:

```
sudo rabbitmq-server -detached
```

I get:

```
Activating RabbitMQ plugins ...
0 plugins activated:
```

That was it. How should I properly shut it down? In the document, it mentions using `rabbitmqctl(1)`, but it's not clear to me what that means. Thanks.

Edit: As per comment below, this is what I get for running `sudo rabbitmqctl stop`:

```
(project_env)mlstr-1:Package mlstr$ sudo rabbitmqctl stop
Password:
Stopping and halting node rabbit@h002 ...
Error: unable to connect to node rabbit@h002: nodedown

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

nodes in question: [rabbit@h002]

hosts, their running nodes and ports:
- h002: [{rabbit,62428},{rabbitmqctl7069,64735}]

current node details:
- node name: rabbitmqctl7069@h002
- home dir: /opt/local/var/lib/rabbitmq
- cookie hash: q7VU0JjCd0VG7jOEF9Hf/g==
```

Why is there still a 'current node'? I have not run any client program but only the RabbitMQ server, does that mean a server is still running?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

It turns out that it is related to permissions. Somehow my rabbitmq server was started with user 'rabbitmq' (which is strange), so that I had to do

```
sudo -u rabbitmq rabbitmqctl stop
```

Answer (score 34):

In my dev environment where I keep it running all the time, I use:

```
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.rabbitmq.plist
```

and to start it

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.rabbitmq.plist
```

Even easier....

```
brew services stop rabbitmq
brew services start rabbitmq
```

Answer (score 29):

Use `rabbitmqctl stop` to stop any node. If you need to specify the node giving you trouble, add the `-n rabbit@[hostname]` option.

Comment: I like this answer!  The command is different than in Windows, and may confuse people.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the shortcut RabbitMQ Service - stop if you don't like the commands

Answer (score 1):

**stop**
sudo systemctl stop rabbitmq-server

**start**
sudo systemctl start rabbitmq-server

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, use PowerShell as Admin, then run

`.\rabbitmq-service.bat stop`

> `stop` Stop the service. The service must be running for this command to have any effect.
>
> https://www.rabbitmq.com/man/rabbitmq-service.8.html

---

<sub>For OP's answer above,

> It turns out that it is related to permissions.

I have no knowledge on this.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

### For mac users

To Stop

```
brew services stop rabbitmq
```

To Start

```
brew services start rabbitmq
```

To Restart

```
brew services restart rabbitmq
```

To Know the status of the server

```
brew services info rabbitmq
```