# shell script to stop the rabbitmq server

Tags: shell, command, rabbitmq

I tried to stop the rabbitmq server from shell script, but its failing to stop

i can run the below command from the shell prompt and could able to stop the rabbitmq server.

```
sh /data/rabbitmq-3.1.5/rabbitmq_server-3.1.5/sbin/rabbitmqctl stop
```

but when i try to run the same command from shell script its not able to identify the "stop" after rabbitmqctl command.

```
Message Received
```

Error: could not recognize  command
Usage: 
rabbitmqctl [-n ] [-q]   []

Comment: I don't see why you would need the leading `sh ` on cmd-line or in a script. can you try that? Good luck.

Comment: I tried even without sh its not working.

Comment: Basically its not accepting the command "stop" after rabbitmqctl. Is there any way we can run the "/data/rabbitmq-3.1.5/rabbitmq_server-3.1.5/sbin/rabbitmqctl stop" as single command.

Comment: do `file /data/rabbitmq-3.1.5/rabbitmq_server-3.1.5/sbin/rabbitmqctl ` If the result is something `script`, then look at file w editor and see if it will process a `stop` argument. Based on Usage msg you quote, it doesn't look to be designed to work that way. Consult more `rabbitmq` doc? As a seperate issue, installing software under a dir named `/data` seems non-standard and possibly error prone (but unlikey the cause of your current problem). I'm leaving for a while. Good luck.!

Comment: Depends on distro etc. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608950/how-do-i-stop-the-rabbitmq-server-on-localhost or try /sbin/service rabbitmq-server stop (RHEL)